# Differentiable loss function for ranking problem in regression model

Tags: machine-learning, regression, loss-function, ranking

In regression problem, we may need a loss function to measure the relative ranking accuracy between targets $y$ and predicted values $y_{pred}$. Abviously, the simple MSE does not consider such ranking relations.

A straight choice is the so-called IC (Information Coefficient)

$$IC\propto corr(\text{rank}(y), \text{rank}(y_{pred}))$$

which use the correlation between two ranks. However, `rank` function is not differentiable, thus it can't be used in loss function for regression which uses gradient propagation to update the parameters.

Another choice might be a modified pairwise ranking loss designed for regression

$$\text{Loss}=\sum_{i, j} \text{max}(0, -(y_{pred}^{(i)}-y_{pred}^{(j)})\cdot(y^{(i)}-y^{(j)}))$$

which is proposed in this paper [https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~zha/papers/fp086-zheng.pdf]. This function is differentiable but also hard to train.

My questions are: (1) Is there any other differentiable loss function that can be applied in ranking problem with regression model;
(2) Can `rank` function be approximated by a differentiable function.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use standard framing as learning to rank the relative positions, thus pairwise loss function.